# How can I swap my primary monitor in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, monitor

Everything is pretty much in the title, I have tested using Display Changer but without success because my monitor are both named "Generic PnP Monitor" so I can't say which screen must be set as the primary. I've seen that i need to download the drivers to get my monitor a name but both of my monitor don't have driver for Windows 10. I would think there must be a way to simply swap the principal screen to the other one or something like that but I haven't seen anyone do it.

Comment: Why do you want to define primary monitor by batch script at all? For a desktop PC with 2 monitors plugged the primary monitor can be switched by exchanging the monitor cables on PC side. And for laptops with an additional monitor plugged there is usually a key (for example Fn + F8) which on pressing switches which monitors are enabled and which one is the primary monitor.

Comment: I want to be able to swap the primary screen quickly before starting a game. I dont want to have to play with the cables everytimes

Comment: Thanks for this additional information. This is indeed a good reason to switch the monitors by command from within a batch file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try nircmd.exe which is a small but powerful command-line utility .

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

> setdisplay {monitor:index/name} [width] [height] [color bits] {refresh rate} {-updatereg} {-allusers}
>
> ....... You can specify the monitor by index (0 for the first monitor, 1 for the second one, and so on) or by specifying a string in the system monitor name...........

Comment: I've used your tool. The correct command to do what i wanted was: nircmd setprimarydisplay 2

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the multi monitor tool, as it allows for more functionality towards switching monitors, such as moving windows as well. Also has a simpler command for the basic task at hand.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html

```
/SetPrimary <Monitor> 

Set the primary monitor.
Example:
MultiMonitorTool.exe /SetPrimary 2
```